# How to queue goals with actionlib

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

As I have understood, with the simple action server, when a new goal comes in, it preempts old ones. From this post http://answers.ros.org/question/9776/action-server-with-more-than-one-action/ it seems that it is possible to put such goals into queues, however it is not clear to me how. Is there any tutorial, or anything providing a guideline for how to implement this?

Thank you for your time:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249020/how-to-queue-goals-with-actionlib/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
After playing a bit around with action-server and simple-action-server, I came up with the below simple solution (it is far from being complete of course), in case someone else might find it useful or as a start point. Also, if you see some pitfall, I'd be glad to hear it:)
First I create a custom simple server as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from gitagent.msg import *
import random
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('package name')
import rospy
from actionlib import ActionServer
from actionlib.server_goal_handle import ServerGoalHandle
import traceback
import time
import threading

class ActionServer:
    def __init__(self, name, ActionSpec, execute_cb=None, auto_start=True):

        self.execute_callback = execute_cb
        self.goal_callback = None
        self.preempt_callback = None

        #create the action server
        self.action_server = ActionServer(name, ActionSpec, self.get_next_gh, self.internal_preempt_callback, auto_start)

        ## @brief Explicitly start the action server, used it auto_start is set to false
    def start(self):
            self.action_server.start()

    ## @brief Sets the status of the active goal to succeeded
    ## @param  result An optional result to send back to any clients of the goal
    def set_succeeded(self, gh, result=None, text=""):
        if not result:
            result = self.get_default_result()
        gh.set_succeeded(result, text)

    def get_default_result(self):
        return self.action_server.ActionResultType()

    def accept_new_goal(self, goal):
        rospy.loginfo("A new goal %s  has been accepted", str(goal.get_goal()))
        goal.set_accepted("This goal has been accepted by the simple action server -- wait for response")

    #If a new goal is received, start new thread on execute
    def get_next_gh(self, goal):
        #self.execute_condition.acquire()

        try:
                rospy.logdebug("A new goal %shas been recieved by the single goal action server", goal.get_goal_id().id)
        
            rospy.loginfo("A new goal %shas been recieved by the single goal action server", goal.get_goal_id().id)

            if self.execute_callback:
                #Start new thread on execute()
                rospy.loginfo("New thread about to be launched on execute")
                try:
                    t = threading.Thread(target=self.execute_callback, args=(goal,))
                    t.start()
                except:
                    rospy.logerr("Error: unable to start thread")
            else:
                rospy.logerr("DEFINE an execute callback moron")
            #self.execute_condition.release()

        except Exception as e:
            rospy.logerr("SimpleActionServer.internal_goal_callback - exception %s", str(e))
            #self.execute_condition.release()

    def internal_preempt_callback(self):
        pass
```

Then, each thread running execute puts the goalhandle in a queue. theLoop treats each item of the queue one after the other.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from gitagent.msg import *
from threading import Lock
import random
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('package name')
import rospy
import actionlib
import Queue
import action_server
import traceback
import time
import threading

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('server', anonymous=True)
        self.queueGoalHandles = Queue.Queue()
        self.server = action_server.ActionServer('server', doMeFavorAction, self.execute, False)
        self.server.start()
        self.keep_track_threads = []
        self.lock = Lock()

    #Needs to be used similarly as handle_serve, in order to block threads respectively.
    def execute(self, goalhandle):
        print 'I got a request'

        # Add tag to identify current thread
        # Task status: -1 ~ FAIL, 0 ~ PENDING, 1 ~ SUCCESS, 10 ~ no thread active
        index = -1

        self.lock.acquire()
        goal = goalhandle.get_goal()
        print 'extracted goal content: ' + str(goal.sender)
        self.keep_track_threads.append({'senderId':int(goal.sender), 'task_status':0})
        # It is assumed that the senderId is unique, that is the server cannot get 2 a second task from the same agent, without returning with the first.
        # {senderID:task_status}
        #self.keep_track_threads.append({data.sender:0})
        index = len(self.keep_track_threads) - 1
        print self.keep_track_threads
        # Put task in a queue, make thread wait until task status is set to success/fail 
        self.queueGoalHandles.put(goalhandle)
        self.lock.release()

        while self.keep_track_threads[index]['task_status'] == 0:
            print 'Task execution is pending'
            rospy.sleep(1)
        print 'Thread: ' + str(self.keep_track_threads[index]['task_status']) + ' has returned'
        result.act_outcome = self.keep_track_threads[index]['task_status']
        self.server.set_succeeded(goalhandle, result)
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.keep_track_threads[index]['task_status'] = 10
        self.lock.release()
        print self.keep_track_threads
        print result

    def theLoop(self):
        print 'Sever started'
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            #print 'Waiting for goal...'
            #Non-blocking
            try:
                item = self.queueGoalHandles.get(False)
                print item

                #Assuming we always accept the goal - set this goal as the current goal
                            self.server.accept_new_goal(item)

                i = 0
                while i <= 10:
                    print i
                    i = i + 1
                    time.sleep(1)
                index = next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(self.keep_track_threads) if d['senderId'] == int(item.get_goal().sender))
                self.keep_track_threads[index]['task_status'] = 1
                #self.keep_track_threads[0]['task_status'] = 1
                print self.keep_track_threads
            except Queue.Empty:
                #print 'empty queue'
                pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        serve = Server()
        serve.theLoop()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        traceback.print_exc()
    except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError, NameError):
        traceback.print_exc()
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Cheers:)

---

Originally posted by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) with karma: 176 on 2016-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4